# NUXTJS how to set props from page to layout?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have home and text pages. They have different headers, but one layout. 
How can I tell `layout` to pass props to the `header` depending on the page?

**Layout:**

```
<template lang="pug">
  .block
    headnav( headertype="mainpage" )
    nuxt
</template>
```

**Pages**

```
<template lang="pug">
  .mainpage
</template>
```

```
<template lang="pug">
  .textpage
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add following code to script section (for example after data):

```
head() {
    return {
        title: '{your page title}'
    }
},
```